# C programming language: type double value of address pointed to by void pointer changes unexpectedly

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, double

I am attempting to complete an exercise in a C book ("Sam's Teach Yourself C in 21 Days", chapter 18, exercise 7).

My challenge is that I am unable to understand why the value of a type double variable array pointed to by a void pointer changes unexpectedly, but the values of other data types I point show as expected.

In the code below, I call a function that returns a void pointer to an array of any data type.  The main() function then prints the values of the array selected by the user.  This program works perfectly it seems, except for the type double value of the 2nd element of a type double array assigned to by a void pointer.  For some reason unknown to me, the value of the 2nd type double variable, pointed to by incrementing the pointer in main(), changes unexpectedly to different numbers of unknown origin (perhaps somewhere in memory).

I have searched stack overflow and other internet sources to understand the root cause of this challenge, but I have failed to see a solution and still do not understand why this is happening.  Please help me understand this.  The line of code where things go wrong is, in my editor, line 63, where I attempt to print the expected value:

```
printf("Lowest value is %f\n\n", *((double *)ptr));
```

Thank you in advance.

Here is a snippet of the code:

```
/* function definition */
void *function(void *x, char type, int size);

/* array definitions */
int array1[] = {100, 200, 300, 400};
double array2[] = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50};
float array3[] = {1.2, 3.5, 35.2, 93};
long array4[] ={2034, 293049, 2039402, 394038};

/* variable definitions */
void *ptr;
char type;
int elements;

int main()
{
    printf("Which data type array do you want to find the largest and smallest");
    printf("values of?\n");
    printf("Options:\ni = int\nd = double\nf = float\nl = long\n\n x or X to exit\n");
    printf("Enter your selection: ");
    scanf("%c", &type);

    switch(type)
    {
        case 'i':
        {
            printf("\nYou selected: type int:\n");
            elements = sizeof(array1) / sizeof(int);
            ptr = malloc(sizeof(int) * 2);
            ptr = function(array1, type, elements);
            printf("\naddress of value pointed to by ptr = %u", (unsigned)ptr);
            printf("\nHighest value is %d\n", *((int *)ptr));
            ptr = ptr + sizeof(int);
            printf("\naddress of value pointed to by ptr = %u\n",     (unsigned)ptr);
            printf("Lowest value is %d\n\n", *((int *)ptr));
            break;
        }
        ...
        default:
        {
            puts("Incorrect input\n");
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

void *function(void *x, char type, int size)
{
    void *ptr[2];
    int count = 0;

    switch(type)
    {
        case 'i':
        {
            int high = ((int *)x)[0];
            printf("\nvalue of void *x = %d\n", high);
            int low = ((int *)x)[1];
            int array[2];
            for (count = 0; count < size; count++)          
            {
                if(((int *)x)[count] > high)
                    high = ((int *)x)[count];
                else if(((int *)x)[count] < low)
                    low =  ((int *)x)[count];
            }
            array[0] = high;
            array[1] = low;

            ptr[0] = malloc(sizeof(int)*2);
            ptr[0] = &array[0];
            ptr[1] = malloc(sizeof(int)*2);
            ptr[1] = &array[1];

            printf("\nWithin function:\n");
            printf("address of array = %lu\n", (long unsigned)array);
            printf("address of array[0] = %lu\n", (long unsigned)&array[0]);
            printf("address of array[1] = %lu\n", (long unsigned)&array[1]);

            printf("\nvalue of array[0] = %d", array[0]);
            printf("\nvalue of array[1] = %d\n", array[1]);         
            printf("\nvalue of ptr[0] = %d", *(int *)ptr[0]);
            printf("\nvalue of ptr[1] = %d\n", *(int  *)ptr[1]);            

            break;
        }
        ...
    }
    return *ptr;
}
```

Comment: next time, please reduce your code to something, that is small and reproduces the error. Not everyone is eager to read thru 20pages of code

Comment: Why would you *ever* do this?

Comment: @H2CO3; This is what happens when someone trying to learn C in **21 days** :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is at least part of your issue:

```
    ptr[0] = malloc(sizeof(double)*2);
    ptr[0] = &array[0];
    ptr[1] = malloc(sizeof(double)*2);
    ptr[1] = &array[1];
```

You alloc some memory, then you immediately leak it. `array` is a local
variable so `ptr` points to garbage after you return. This would explain
why your print statements seem correct inside the function and then wrong
after you leave the function.

There are identical problems in the code blocks for the other types.

Answer (score 0):

Your program behavior is *undefined*. You are printing all the pointer values by using `%u` specifier which is wrong. You should use `%p` specifier to print pointer values.

```
 printf("\naddress of value pointed to by ptr = %p", (void *)ptr);
```